# Create SQL Server database from C# - using parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am trying to put up a code to create a databases from my C# code (asp.net website).

This is my code:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE @dbname", nn);
myCommand.Parameters.Add("dbname", dbname);

myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
nn.Close();
```

well, its not working. its giving me an error:

> *incorrect syntax near '@dbname'*

BUT. if I won't use parameters, people can SQL inj to my database. do you have any idea how can use anything, to get the database name from a textbox. and that people can't SQL inj me database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use parameters in `CREATE DATABASE` or other DDL commands.

I'd suggest using [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162577%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) instead of SQL

Comment: I see that link, but i can't understand anything, do you have a code sample?

Comment: Not to be snarky, but the posted link has the simplest possible sample code. Work at understanding it.